# java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != com.example.haoch.sensoring.Blesave

Tags: java, android, android-studio

everyone, I was encountered some formate prolem when I running my java code, the code is as follows:

```
public class Blesave {

private int rssi1, rssi2, rssi3, rssi4;
private int major, minor1,minor2, minor3, minor4, txpower1,txpower2, txpower3, txpower4;
private double accuracy1, accuracy2, accuracy3, accuracy4;
private long timestamp, timeInternal;
private String uuid;

public Blesave(long timestamp, long timeInternal, String uuid, int major,
               int minor1, double accuracy1, int txpower1, int rssi1,
               int minor2, double accuracy2, int txpower2, int rssi2,
               int minor3, double accuracy3, int txpower3, int rssi3,
               int minor4, double accuracy4, int txpower4, int rssi4){

    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.timeInternal = timeInternal;
    this.uuid = uuid;
    this.major = major;
    this.minor1 = minor1;
    this.minor2 = minor2;
    this.minor3 = minor3;
    this.minor4 = minor4;
    this.txpower1 = txpower1;
    this.txpower2 = txpower2;
    this.txpower3 = txpower3;
    this.txpower4 = txpower4;
    this.accuracy1 = accuracy1;
    this.accuracy2 = accuracy2;
    this.accuracy3 = accuracy3;
    this.accuracy4 = accuracy4;
    this.rssi1 = rssi1;
    this.rssi2 = rssi2;
    this.rssi3 = rssi3;
    this.rssi4 = rssi4;
}

public String getDataInCSV() {
    return String.format(Locale.KOREA, "%d,%d,%s,%d,%d,%f,%d,%d,%d,%f,%d,%d,%d,%f,%d,%d,%d,%f,%d,%d",
            this.timestamp, this.timeInternal, this.uuid, this.major,
            this.minor1, this.accuracy1,this.txpower1,this,rssi1,
            this.minor2, this.accuracy2,this.txpower2,this,rssi2,
            this.minor3, this.accuracy3,this.txpower3,this,rssi3,
            this.minor4, this.accuracy4,this.txpower4,this,rssi4);
}
}
```

But when I run this code, It will show the following errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: org.sensingkit.crowdsensing_android, PID: 21490
              java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != 
com.example.haoch.sensoring.Blesave
                  at 
java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4135)
                  at 
java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2832)
                  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2786)
                  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2491)
                  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2426)
                  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2670)
                  at com.example.haoch.sensoring.Blesave.getDataInCSV(Blesave.java:47)
                  at com.example.haoch.sensoring.RecoBackgroundRangingService.storeBeaconIntoCSV(RecoBackgroundRangingService.java:161)
                  at com.example.haoch.sensoring.RecoBackgroundRangingService.didRangeBeaconsInRegion(RecoBackgroundRangingService.java:146)
                  at com.perples.recosdk.a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6363)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Can someone help me? I will quite appreciate, I think this is formate problem related to %d problem, But I am not sure where it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument list includes a last column of `this,rssi1`, `this,rssi2`, etc. These commas are probably meant to be periods, so you'd be passing `this.rssi1`, but as-is you are passing `this` and `rssi1`.